# Firestore limitations on queries and sorting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to create `.orderBy` and `.where` in one query but realized its not possible

```
query.where("price", "<", filter.price).orderBy("registeredAt",'desc');
```

So according to Docs you can't have them together.

Now, imagine a home rental DB, one want to query for `price < 1000`, `Firestore` will return tones of irrelevant results since those records **have a very old date (registeredAt)**.

If i sort them on client side i still lost A LOT of data in this query since prices are a match but half dates are old.

I then thought about cleaning my own DB and set those houses as `inactive`, and search with multiple filters :

```
  query.where("price", "<", filter.price);
  query=query.where("active", "==", true);
```

Which is also **impossible** (!) since you can't do this on multiple fields.

I then thought, **what if the owner wants to set his house to** `inactive` and not to be included in queries now ? i can't query for `active` field **and** sort by date / query prices.

This is a *very simple* scenario, and i just can't seems to find a way to do this, ***without*** sorting locally and losing relevant data.

Is `Firestore` so limited or am I missing something ?

There are 3 important fields here, `price`, `date`, `active`, and I need to count all of them when i search.

The last solution i have is to actively move old listing from one collection to another, which seems like a big mess and bad practice (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = query.where("price", "<", filter.price);
query = query.where("active", "==", true);
```

This is posssible with a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). You can combine **one** range (`<` etc) filter with as many `==` as you need.

You can also create predefined ranges (*from* price *to* price for prices, year_month for dates), so that you can use them in equality (or [in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)-array) filters instead of range filters.

Comment: Thanks so much, so no way to combine date here (sort by date) and also range? the first option i am going to explore now, but can you tell more about the predefined ranges ? where can i see example?

Comment: So  i was reading about indexs and i still can't see how it helps me to first use 2 where, and second combine somehow date so i get latest dates only. Can you give me a clue?

Comment: @phamng for example, you can add a `monthString` field, and put the date there as a string in `yyyy-MM` format. Then you can query for documents of the past two months by doing `where('monthString', 'in', ['2021-01', '2020-12'])`

Comment: then, if you try to combine it with a price range `where`, you will get an error. That error will give you a link. Following that link will take you to google cloud console where you can enable the required index for that particular query

Comment: see this video https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI (How do queries work in Cloud Firestore? | Get to know Cloud Firestore #2)

Comment: Thanks so so much, i just had that same idea to create a string date and search for equality, but it seems like a bad practice. Anyway thanks !